# IUIAutomationStylesPattern implementing issue

Tags: c++, windows, ui-automation

I am trying to use uiautomation to get a color of an element of paint application.

I can easily access their size and state etc but i cant seem to find a way to get their background color? lets say i want to retrieve the color of the "new" button how do i do that?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Here they did provide a property to retrieve the currentfillcolor property but it says that client application do not implement IUIAutomationStylesPattern interface. But then why did they provide it in the "UI Automation Client Programmers" section?

I have tried it but there is no IUIAutomationStylesPattern type available for me.

Can anyone help me in finding a way to make it work or if there's another way of approaching it?